# File Activation in Windows Store app in C#?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

I m tryin to make metro Media Player ,but I have a problem in file activation i.e when I open mp3 file from Windows explorer, it open my app But Doesn,t get Arguments, how can I get file or name of file in text block for which my app is launched,i saw many methods in different Websites,But I can't Solve,

Answer (score 1):

here is a really good explanation on how to do this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779669.aspx

you can get the file name and file size here:

```
protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
{
   // TODO: Handle file activation
   // The number of files received is args.Files.Size
   // The first file is args.Files[0].Name
}
```